# Can we throw Parent type exception in the method if we written throws child type exception in the method signature?

Tags: java, exception

```
public void foo1() throws OException
{
    try {

    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

**OException extends Exception**

OException is an API Class provided by third-party

I'm getting compilation error in catch block at throw e statement saying

> unhandled exception type exception

Is this because I cannot throw Parent type Exception as in the method signature I have written throws OException ?

I am able to resolve this compilation error with below two ways:-

- If I throws Exception in the method signature instead of OException
- If I throw OException in the catch block instead of parent type Exception e

One of my friend opens the same code in his workspace and it is not giving him any complication error so I am confused about what exactly is happening here.

Could anyone please Shed some light?

Comment: Ideally, you should be able to do this. Try checking the package names or may restart the IDE.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh aleady did

Comment: Well, no, you can't, and the compiler has already told you so. Unclear why you're even asking.

Comment: @user207421 I am asking because my friend able to compile and run the same code while I am getting this compilation error

Comment: Remove the parentheses in your signature. Change thows OException() to throws OException

Comment: It can't work because `Exception` > `OException`. So for example, with your current code, you would be able to throw an `IOException` without declaring it

Answer (score 2):

`Exception` is a checked exception type. This means that you must catch it (using `try { ... } catch(Exception ex) { ... }` or declare it in the method using `throws`.

Because `Exception` class is above `OException` in the exception hierarchy, you must change the `throws OException` with `throws Exception`.

If the caught and rethrown exception type was `OException`, the `throws` exception declaration would be ok as it is.